# load timeline of public google+ account into android app

Tags: android, google-plus

Hi I am looking for a way how to load a user timeline posts (public account) into android app.
I looked over https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/ but did not really found a way to do this. 
I already implemented a same functionality for twitter using twitter API. just calling GET method like: (https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=ACCOUNT_NAME).

Is it a way to do the same for google+ ?

Regards

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/

Comment: thanks! I would check this